# How to create a NULL Boolean column in a pyspark dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark

I have a Boolean column that is sometimes NULL and want to assign it as such. My code:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
df = df.withColumn('my_column_name', F.lit(None).cast("string"))
```

My error: Column type: BOOLEAN, Parquet schema: optional byte_array

My attempted solution was
`df = df.withColumn('my_column_name', F.lit(None).cast('boolean'))` but this doesn't seem right

Comment: I think the F.when function from the pyspark.sql.functions work here

Answer (score 1):

Using the F.when function you can assign a value NULL on a condition,

so for your problem as example this will be:

```
df = df.withColumn('my_column_name', F.when(F.col("condition_column").isNull(), None).otherwise(F.col("condition_column")))
```

If you want to cast it you would need to use the `PySpark` null function or `lit(None)` to create a `null` literal of the appropriate datatype

Comment: Would just putting "None" be accepted as a correct BOOLEAN data type value? I feel like we would need to cast it (but I could be wrong)

Comment: yes, to cast it you need to use the PySpark null function or lit(None) to create a null literal of the appropriate datatype

Comment: Cool! Can you update your answer? I'll accept it after